# Mounting fstab using mount -a not working like regular mount

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, sysvinit

So I'm writing an custom init script and I want to mount / as rw. In /etc/init.d/rcS when I use `mount -t ext4 -o remount /dev/sda /` it does remount as rw but when I do `mount -a` (or I even tried `mount -a -o remount`) with fstab:

```
/dev/sda                 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
```

it doesn't and / is mounted as ro. What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to mount "/dev/sda" (the disk itself), not "/dev/sda1" / "/dev/sda2" (the first or other partitions on it)

Answer (score 0):

You should mount partitions on your disk (e.g. /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2) to a certain folder, not disk by self.

However, it would be better if you replace the names of partitions with UUID's.
Use `blkid` to learn UUID's of your partitions on the disk.